# Unexpected end of input in Postgresql stored procedure multidimensial array parameter

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.4

I have built stored procedure in PostgreSql which accept multidimensial array parameters like below

```
SELECT horecami.insert_obj_common(
'{"(5, 2, LLLLL rest, 46181, a@a.com, ooo, kkk, 12:09, 20:40, 23, true, 49.667, 48.232, fu, 2011-12-15 15:28:19+04, 2011-12-15 15:28:19+04, 3, 1)"}'::obj_special[],
    '{"(1, 3, q1, q2, q3,  q4, qson  latest, true, 2011-12-15 15:28:19+04, 2, 2, 3, 2011-12-15 15:28:19+04, ' ||  '{"(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)"}'::horecami.obj_soft_hardware[] || ')"}'::obj_soft[]

);
```

Inside this procedure there ara foreach loops that works without problem.
But when i added last extra parametr as array (horecami.obj_soft_hardware[]) it gives me malformed array error.
This is error

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"(1, 3, q1, q2, q3,  q4, qson  latest, true, 2011-12-15 15:28:19+04, 2, 2, 3, 2011-12-15 15:28:19+04, "
LINE 3:  '{"(1, 3, q1, q2, q3,  q4, qson  latest, true, 2011-12-15 1...
     ^
DETAIL:  Unexpected end of input.
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 202
```

It must return number

I guess this syntac error.
Thanks beforehands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a multi-dimensional array; you've got an array containing a composite type, which in turn contains an array containing a composite type.

When writing this as a string literal, certain characters have to be escaped (e.g. strings with spaces need quotes, and those quotes need escaping). Then at nested levels they all need to be double quoted and escaped.

To determine what the string literal should look like, just create it using actual arrays and rows (or composite types), then cast to text to get the literal string value with all fields correctly quoted and escaped:

```
SELECT ARRAY[ROW(1, 3, 'q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'qson  latest', ARRAY[ROW(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)])]::TEXT
```

Returns:

```
{"(1,3,q1,q2,q3,q4,\"qson  latest\",\"{\"\"(1,1,1,1,1)\"\"}\")"}
```

Comment: Thank you very much